# Can I Convert a 'varchar' column to a 'datetime' type

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a webpage that is used to access a database and look up when appointments are set. It's been setup and used for a couple months but now we want to change the column that stores the 'appointment date' from 'varchar' to 'datetime'. The problem is that the varchar date is put into the database as 'Friday, June 10, 2015' for example. I've tried to use 'CONVERT', 'PARSE', 'DECLARE', and 'SELECT PARSE'. I always get a 'incorrect syntax' error. Is this possible? And if so what is the correct syntax?

Comment: What is the syntax you are using that gives incorrect syntax?

Comment: check str_to_date function. [link]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql. And what is the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the STR_TO_DATE function like so:

```
STR_TO_DATE('Friday, June 10, 2015', '%W, %M %e, %Y')
```

The above example assumes a day format that has NO leading zeros (e.g. '1' and not '01'). For more info on the format specifiers, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

**EDIT:** Having re-read your question, I'm not totally clear on how you want to use this conversion... If you're trying to convert the way that the column is stored in your database, then I would suggest that you create a new DATE type column in the table and run an UPDATE to set the the value for each row like so:

```
UPDATE table SET newDateCol = STR_TO_DATE(oldVarcharCol, '%W, %M %e, %Y');
```

Then you can drop the old column and rename the new one to whatever you like. Keep in mind that this may impact other parts of your system that are relying on that field being a VARCHAR.

Hope this helps!